# Ambari can't start namenode with a connection exception

Tags: hadoop, ambari, connection-refused

I have been strapped in this for a few days,I tried a lot of methods on the Internet but it didn't work,so I register on stackoverflow and write my first question.
My environment is HDP2.4 and Ubuntu14.04 LTS

the log information is like this:

```
safemode: Call From master/9.119.131.105 to master:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2016-04-21 15:59:57,796 - Retrying after 10 seconds. Reason: Execution of '/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-namenode/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -fs hdfs://master:8020 -safemode get | grep 'Safe mode is OFF'' returned 1. safemode: Call From master/9.119.131.105 to master:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

(1).At first I tried to avoid the safemode,but it isn't the key of this issue.

(2).Then I started to work on the 8020 port of master,master is the namenode of my cluster and I am sure that the hosts file is correct:

```
9.119.131.105 master
```

(3).ssh function is good,the four nodes in the cluster can load each other without passcodes

(4).I'm sure the fire wall is off

```
# /etc/init.d/iptables stop

# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

(5).I also tried to open the 8020 port manually:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8020 -j ACCEPT
```

it still didn't work.....

(6).I tried :

```
# telnet master 8020
```

but:

```
telnet:Unable to connect to remote host: Connect refused
```

(7).I find that not only the 8020 port can't work,but also 50070 can't work

(8).I'm sure the parameters in the configure files is 8020:

```
fs.defaultFS
hdfs://master:8020

dfs.namenode.rpc-address
master:8020
```

I'm expecting somebody can help me,I will be very appreciate about thant.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check if port 8020 is open , using netstat -a command ?

Comment: @ShubhangiPardeshi Thx for reply,I checked 8020 with netstat command and 8020 is not open,so the question is why it isn't open....I think 8020 should open with the start progress of namenode,but it didn't.As I said in (5) above,I can't open it manually either.Any suggestions?